# Excluding Lower levels in Nlog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

in Nlog

i know there are

```
trace
debug
info
warn
error
fatal
```

levels, and that if i printed "warn" by example higher levels wont be printed , now problem is how do i disable lower levels too ?!

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it

i used minlevel , maxlevel and level(only log specific level)...

Answer (score 0):

Use Minlevel

example  `<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" />`

This will disable all levels lower than "Error"